# Error while inserting data in database using Ajax in Django after validating the ModelForm

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am creating a Django ModelForm

It is partially working as if I do not validate the form i.e. if I remove `if form.is_valid():` statement from the code **then values got inserted in the database properly**

but if I use it, then it shows error in the console as `print("Errors ", form_to_insert_data.errors)` as:

`<ul class="errorlist"><li>name<ul class="errorlist"><li>write name</li></ul></li><li>ini_stg<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>dev_stg<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>mid_stg<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>end_stg<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>ini_kc<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>dev_kc<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>mid_kc<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>end_kc<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>root_len<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`

However, I am inserting all the values properly in the form i.e. noting is left blank.

and if I don't pass `print("Errors ", form_to_insert_data.errors)`, then the error appears as

```
Internal Server Error: /url_for_crop_data_to_insert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_Abhilash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python_Abhilash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 188, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "C:\Python_Abhilash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 309, in check_response
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view waterbalance.views.save_inserted_cropdata didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

The code is as below

***Model***

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

class CropDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ini_stg = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)])
    dev_stg = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)])
    mid_stg = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)])
    end_stg = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)])
    ini_kc = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(2.0)])
    dev_kc = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(2.0)])
    mid_kc = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(2.0)])
    end_kc = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(2.0)])
    root_len = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(2000)])
```

***View***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import JsonResponse
from waterbalance.forms import add_crop_details_to_database
from waterbalance.models import CropDetail

def save_inserted_cropdata(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = add_crop_details_to_database(request.POST)
        print("form", form)
        if form.is_valid():

            CropName = request.POST["CropName"]
            print("CropName", CropName)
            InitialStage = request.POST["InitialStage"]
            DevelopmentStage = request.POST["DevelopmentStage"]
            MidStage = request.POST["MidStage"]
            EndStage = request.POST["EndStage"]
            InitialKc = request.POST["InitialKc"]
            DevelopmentKc = request.POST["DevelopmentKc"]
            MidStageKc = request.POST["MidStageKc"]
            EndStageKc = request.POST["EndStageKc"]
            RootLength = request.POST["RootLength"]

            crop_data_to_pass = CropDetail(name=CropName, ini_stg=InitialStage, dev_stg=DevelopmentStage, mid_stg=MidStage, end_stg=EndStage,ini_kc=InitialKc, dev_kc=DevelopmentKc,  mid_kc=MidStageKc, end_kc=EndStageKc, root_len=RootLength)

            crop_data_to_pass.save()

            return JsonResponse({'status': 'Save'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': "Failed"})
```

***Form***

```
from django import forms
from waterbalance.models import CropDetail

class add_crop_details_to_database(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:

        model = CropDetail

        fields = ["name", "ini_stg", "dev_stg", "mid_stg", "end_stg", "ini_kc", "dev_kc", "mid_kc", "end_kc", "root_len"]

        labels = {"name":"Crop Name", "ini_stg":"Initial Stage Duration", "dev_stg":"Development Stage Duration", "mid_stg":"Mid-Season Stage Duration", "end_stg":"End-Season Stage Duration", "ini_kc":"Initial Stage Crop Coefficient", "dev_kc":"Development Stage Crop Coefficient", "mid_kc":"Mid-Season Stage Crop Coefficient", "end_kc":"End-Season Stage Crop Coefficient", "root_len":"Root Length (mm)"}

        widgets = {
            "name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"name_id"}),
            "ini_stg":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"ini_stg_id"}),
            "dev_stg":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"dev_stg_id"}),
            "mid_stg":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"mid_stg_id"}),
            "end_stg":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"end_stg_id"}),
            "ini_kc":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"ini_kc_id"}),
            "dev_kc":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"dev_kc_id"}),
            "mid_kc":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"mid_kc_id"}),
            "end_kc":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"end_kc_id"}),
            "root_len":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control", "id":"root_len_id"})
        }
```

***URLs***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from waterbalance import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('login', views.loginUser, name="login"),
    path('logout', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('cropdatabase', views.cropdatabase, name='cropdatabase'),
    path('url_for_crop_data_to_insert', views.save_inserted_cropdata, name='url_for_crop_data_to_insert'),
]
```

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Database Form</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './CSS/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './CSS/font-awesome.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './CSS/newStyle.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './JS/crop_names.js' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static './CSS/new_styles_for_frame_weather.css' %}" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://mausam.imd.gov.in/ico/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <h2 class="text-center alert alert-danger"> Insert Crop Details in Database</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h4 class="text-center alert alert-info">Add/Update Crop Database</h4>
                <form class="text-left alert alert-primary" action="/Adding Data to Crop Database/" method="post" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form_cropdatabase}}
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit_to_database" value="Save in Database">
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <h4 class="text-center alert alert-info">Crops in existing Database</h4>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Sr. No.</th>
                            <th scope="col">Crop Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Initial Stage Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">Development Stage Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">Mid-Season Stage Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">End-Season Stage Duration</th>
                            <th scope="col">Initial Stage Kc</th>
                            <th scope="col">Development Stage Kc</th>
                            <th scope="col">Mid-Season Stage Kc</th>
                            <th scope="col">End-Season Stage Kc</th>
                            <th scope="col">Root Length (mm)</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for crop in fetch_db_base %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>  {{crop.id}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.name}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.ini_stg}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.dev_stg}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.mid_stg}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.end_stg}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.ini_kc}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.dev_kc}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.mid_kc}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.end_kc}}  </td>
                            <td>  {{crop.root_len}}  </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" 
                                data-sid="{{crop.id}}"
                                class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                                value="Edit">

                                <input type="button" 
                                data-sid="{{crop.id}}"
                                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                                value="Delete">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

########### AJAX Request Here ####################################################

<script>
$("#submit_to_database").click(function(){
    console.log("Save in database button clicked")
let crop_name = $("#name_id").val()
let initial_stage = $("#ini_stg_id").val()
let development_stage = $("#dev_stg_id").val()
let mid_stage = $("#mid_stg_id").val()
let end_stage = $("#end_stg_id").val()
let initial_Kc = $("#ini_kc_id").val()
let development_Kc = $("#dev_kc_id").val()
let mid_stage_Kc = $("#mid_kc_id").val()
let end_stage_Kc = $("#end_kc_id").val()
let root_length = $("#root_len_id").val() 
let CSRF_Tkn = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val() 
if (crop_name == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the Crop Name here")
} else if (initial_stage == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the Number of days in Initial stage here")
}else if (development_stage == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the Number of days in Development stage here")
}else if (mid_stage == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the Number of days in Middle stage here")
}else if (end_stage == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the Number of days in End stage here")
}else if (initial_Kc == ""){
    console.log("Please enter value of Crop Coefficient at initial stage here")
}else if (development_Kc == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the value of Crop Coefficient at Development stage here")
}else if (mid_stage_Kc == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the value of Crop Coefficient at Middle stage here")
}else if (end_stage_Kc == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the value of Crop Coefficient at End stage here")
}else if (root_length == ""){
    console.log("Please enter the Root length of crop in millimeters here")
} else {
    crop_data_to_insert = {CropName: crop_name, InitialStage: initial_stage, DevelopmentStage: development_stage, MidStage: mid_stage, EndStage: end_stage, InitialKc: initial_Kc, DevelopmentKc: development_Kc, MidStageKc: mid_stage_Kc, EndStageKc: end_stage_Kc, RootLength: root_length, csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRF_Tkn};
    console.log("crop_data_to_insert",  crop_data_to_insert)
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'url_for_crop_data_to_insert' %}",
        method:"POST",
        data:crop_data_to_insert,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            console.log("data", data)
        }
    })
}
});
</script>

</html>
```

How to insert values in database after validation?

Comment: Where's your view that renders the template?

Comment: @IainShelvington , I am quiet new to Django, and wrote this code by followed the Docs, but still may be wrong., isn't ```save_inserted_cropdata``` the view ?

Comment: No that view doesn't render a template

Comment: You are sending the wrong field/data names in your request, for example you should be submitting data with the key `ini_stg` but you change it to `InitialStage` for some reason?

Comment: It was getting passed when i print the values in console, so thought it is working fine. No specific reason to change. And I am not sure about the view, As I remove the validation statement from the ```save_inserted_cropdata```, the data got inserted properly

Comment: How to render the tempelate in view here, can you please refer to some doc ? like I created the ```save_inserted_cropdata``` ```view``` separately for it

Comment: The ModelForm is expecting the keys inn your data to match the field names on your model, you don't use the correct names so the form doesn't pick up the data correctly. Change the keys in your data to match the model field names and just use `form.save()` after checking it's valid, no need to manually fiddle with the data let the form do all the work

Comment: Should I change the Ajax like ```crop_data_to_insert = {CropName: crop_name, InitialStage: initial_stage``` to match with ModelForm Fields ```crop_data_to_insert = {name: crop_name, ini_stg: initial_stage``` ?

Comment: Yes, you would then be submitting data that the model form can understand and handle for you so you don't need to manually extract the POST data or create the instance

Comment: after doing so the error is ```django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'CropName'```

Comment: Expected, remove all manual handling of POST data like `CropName = request.POST["CropName"]`, just call `form.save()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @IainShelvington, However it worked both ways, ```1st``` as you suggested & ```2nd``` when I changed the POST request keys in view to match with ModelForm Fields```CropName = request.POST["name"], InitialStage = request.POST["ini_stg"], DevelopmentStage = request.POST["dev_stg"] and so on```